# Fail to install ubuntu 18 on Workstation hp Z8 G4

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I have workstation hp Z8 G4 and trying to install ubuntu 18

*Z8 G4 specification

-hp linux-ready

-os load to sata/sas

-intel 6136 xeon3.0 *2

-nVidia Qdr GV100 32GB *2

First, I inseted USB with ubuntu 18 image and power on.

In GNU GRUB, I selected Try ubuntu without installing.(also Install ubuntu)

After that the screen turns black. And no response.

To fix it, tried paramset nomodeset, nouveau.modeset=0 but wont work, Same black screen.

Do I have to install with specific version Or specific param?

Comment: The parameter to add is `nomodeset` only. That and assuring you're booting in UEFI mode, of course.

Comment: I'd suggest running the 'check install media` option, but also check what you are trying to install. There is no Ubuntu 18 (*so you may have something else*), there is Ubuntu Core 18 (*an IoT appliance release*), Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & Ubuntu 18.10 (which will be EOL soon, so use the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu 19.04). For a workstation you usually want a desktop version.

Comment: I have the same system (HP Z8 G4), and setting just "nomodeset" has worked.
Change "quiet splash ---" to "quiet splash nomodeset" in the edit.